# Launch an exe and have tail -f in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cmder

I have an exe file that launches a specific server and logs information onto a .log file:

- server.exe
- server.log

I would like to launch the server from a bat file in a way that, the server starts and meanwhile I can see the updated server log.

In short, I'd like to do:

> server.exe
> tail -f server.log

in one single step, in one single cmder tab.

My problem is that the server, when launching remains on a "listening" state, so my bat file never reaches the `tail` part.

What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start server.exe without waiting by using command start.

```
start server.exe 
tail -f server.log
```